# Creating feature with empty geometry using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, features, point-creation, null-geometry

I would like to create a model point dataset in QGIS 3.0.3 with Python in the QGIS Python Console to do some testing. Specifically, I  want to create a point dataset that has a feature with an empty geometry, and, another feature with a NULL geometry.

What I have tried is:

```py
layer = QgsVectorLayer('Point?crs=epsg:4326&field=id:string&field=type:string','ModelPoints',"memory")
pr = layer.dataProvider()

points = {}
points['Pt1'] = ['(1,1)', QgsPointXY(1,1)]
points['Pt2'] = ['(2,1)', QgsPointXY(1,1)]
points['Pt3'] = ['(4,1)', QgsPointXY(1,1)]
points['Pt4'] = ['empty', QgsPointXY()]
points['Pt5'] = ['null', None]

for id, point in points.items():
    pt = QgsFeature()   
    pt.setAttributes([id,point[0]])
    if point[1] is not None:
        pt.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(point[1]))
    print(pt.geometry().asWkt())    
    pr.addFeature(pt)

layer.updateExtents()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

In this code, the empty point geometry is intended to be created by:

```py
pt.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY())
```

However, the result is:

```py
pt.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(0,0))
```

So, my code is making a point with the vertex (0,0), but, whereas I need a point (or a geometry) with no vertices.

The approaches `g = QgsGeometry.fromWkt('POINT')` and `g = QgsGeometry.fromWkt('POINT EMPTY')` both result in a NULL geometry as shown by using `print(g.isNull())`.

Comment: I guess that QGIS has methods for handling WKT so you could have a try with WKT `POINT EMPTY`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach to creating an empty geometry is:

```py
QgsGeometry.fromWkt('LineString()')
```

These can be tested by:

```py
QgsGeometry.fromWkt('LineString()').isEmpty() # True
QgsGeometry.fromWkt('LineString()').isNull() # False
```

However, for an empty point, QGIS is currently displaying:

```py
QgsGeometry.fromWkt('Point()').isNull() # True
```

So, empty line data sets can be constructed, but, there maybe an error for empty point datasets.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, if it's obvious, but you can simply create an instance of [`QgsGeometry`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html) without arguments.

For example

```py
geom = QgsGeometry()
print(geom.isNull()) #True
print(geom.isEmpty()) #True
```

Answer (score 0):

This creates a generic null geometry:

```
QgsGeometry().fromWkt('')
```

Qgis 3.10.5

Comment: but causes issues with the whole layer